# How do I add Angularjs to Spring petclinic for use on a web server?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am decomposing [the Angularjs branch of the Spring petclinic sample app](https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic) to figure out how it works.  Towards that end, I deleted the entire contents of [src/main/webapp/](https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/webapp) and replaced it with:

```
src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.cs
src/main/webapp/resources/css/my.css
src/main/webapp/js/lib/angular.js
src/main/webapp/includes/index_testincl.html
src/main/webapp/testController.js
src/main/webapp/index.html
```

There is nothing else in [`src/main/webapp/`](https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/webapp) besides the 6 files listed above.

The Spring config files remain the same and are at [this link](https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/resources/spring).

The stripped and minimally-replaced version works perfectly in Eclipse on a local devbox when called from `localhost:8080/appname`, but when I bundle it into a war file and upload it to a remote server, it is not able to serve the JavaScript, CSS, or HTML include files that are a critical part of its functioning.  What do I need to change in the setup in order to get the Angularjs functionality to work properly in the remote web server when someone types mydomain.com into their browser?

There is no CSS or JavaScript in the content served by the remote web server, so there are no links.  There is only plain text.  When I have the network tab of the developer tools open in Firefox, the following output is displayed:

[image]

  
There is no console tab output for any of the above requests.
  
The goal is to better understand how the connection between AngularJS and Spring MVC needs to be set up. The more sophisticated versions built up from these simple files need to do database transactions using Java and Spring MVC.  Thus, any answer needs to be compatible with Java and Spring MVC.    
  
The Tomcat server that serves up mydomain.com at the remote web server also successfully serves up other war files that are spring-only using jsp, so the problem is related to adding AngularJS and HTML. 
  
Note: The exact clone of the AngularJS Spring petclinic app also does not run when bundled into a war and deployed at mydomain.com, but this OP uses a greatly simplified AngularJS app in order to more effectively isolate the specific mechanism required to get Tomcat, spring-mvc, and AngularJS to work together on a web server.

---

### Steps to recreate this problem

The problem can be recreated with the following steps:

1.) Navigate to `/home/username/git`

2.) git clone https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic.git

3.) Eclipse -> File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven project

4.) Eclipse -> Project Explorer -> Rt-Click-Project -> Maven -> Download Sources

5.) Eclipse -> Project Explorer -> Rt-Click-Project -> Maven -> Update Project

6.) Delete everything in `src/main/webapp` except keep: `src/main/webapp/js/lib/angular.js`

7.) Download `bootstrap.css` version 3.3.5 from this url: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/  (It is in a zip file.) Once it is downloaded, copy it to the following location in the project:  `src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.cs`  (You will need to create the `src/main/webapp/resources/` and `src/main/webapp/resources/css` directories.)

8.) Create `src/main/webapp/resources/css/my.css` to include whatever minimal styles you want.

9.) Create `src/main/webapp/index.html` and add the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title of page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/my.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testController.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="testController">  
<table width=100%>
    <tr>
        <td align=center>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th class="toc"> 
                        <a class="btn btn-success" role="button" ng-click="homeFunc()">Home</a>
                    </th>
                    <th class="toc">
                        <a class="btn btn-success" role="button" ng-click="testFunc()">Include file</a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
              <div ng-if="functype == 'home'">
                Home page.
              </div>
              <div ng-if="functype == 'test'">
                <div ng-include="'includes/index_testincl.html'"></div>
              </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

10.) Create `src/main/webapp/includes/index_testincl.html` and include the following code:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="body">If the link shows this, then JavaScript works!</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

11.) Create `src/main/webapp/testController.js`  and include the following:

```
// create Angular app
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

// create Angular controller
testApp.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.functype = 'home';

    //below functions handle navigation links
    $scope.homeFunc = function() {
        $scope.functype = 'home';
    }
    $scope.testFunc = function() {
        $scope.functype = 'test';
    }

}]);
```

12.) Eclipse -> Project Explorer -> Rt-Click-Project -> Run As..Maven Build

13.) Eclipse -> Project Explorer -> Rt-Click-Project -> Refresh

14.) Copy the way to some remote Tomcat server and try to load it from a web browser by typing anydomain.com.

That is it. The problem should be recreated.

What needs to be changed in order for the above minimal AngularJS app to run properly on the remote Tomcat web server when requests are made to anydomain.com?